# Warning in install.packages: cannot open UR HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

Tags: r, rstudio

When running `install.packages` in the latest R (3.4) and RStudio 1.0.143 I get the following warning

```
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

This appears no matter what package(s) I select, however this does not appear to effect package installation. I tried clearing my `~/.rstudio-desktop`, `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library` and reinstalling R and this warning still persists. Evening changing CRAN mirrors appears to have no effect as a similar warning appears. Below is my session information.

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] datasets  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0
```

Comment: I think it's a product of the CRAN mirror still holding its data in a directory with an old R version number. As far as I can tell, it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: I too have this problem, regardless of which package I try to install or update. Same as OP, everything will still install correctly as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

Just to let people know: this issue is coming from the R-Studio IDE. It will be fixed in the newest version. For more info: see [this link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115006223707-New-version-of-RStudio-gives-warning-on-package-install).

**EDIT:**

With the new version (1.0.153) this issue has been resolved!

Answer (score 4):

As @ManualS already acknowledged this is an issue with the RStudio 1.0.143. As long as there is no fix the following workaround works fine:

1. Close RStudio and start base R
2. Install package there, either by
   `install.packages("packagename")` or by menu "Packages/Install package(s)"
3. Close base R and start RStudio again

A full support session (for the [OneR](https://cran.r-project.org/package=OneR) package) with more details can be found here: https://github.com/vonjd/OneR/issues/4